# How to do DCE-RPC or SMB request to MS-RPC in GOLANG?

Tags: go, security, smb, dce, msrpc

I need to connect to MS-RPC and call MS-EVEN lib functions, but I can't find any implementations written in golang. I know about impacket, i took request struct arguments from this repo, but i need to do it in go. It's even sadder that wireshark doesn't have a parser for ms-even functions.

I've been trying to connect to ms-even for a month now. I tried to use [this](https://github.com/jfjallid/go-smb) repository that connects to the MS-rpc server using smb, changing the ms-srvs parameters to ms-event parameters, but apparently the request structure is incorrect or something else, but it does not work. The microsoft documentation tells me absolutely nothing, it's terrible. Is there someone here who can help me to figure out the topic and finally call ELFTOpenELW?